# Django saving objects - works, but values of objects seem to be cached until I restart server

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm writing an app for tagging photos. One of the views handles adding new tags and without boilerplate for POST/GET and handling field errors it does this:

```
tagName = request.cleaned_attributes['tagName']
t = Tag.objects.create(name = tagName)
t.save()
```

Now in a view for another request to retrieve all tags I have:

```
tags = Tag.objects.all()
```

I see the data only after restarting Django development server, which is odd to me. Seems like `Tag.objects.all()` has some caching mechanism that is not invalidated properly? The data is for sure saved to the database.

The database backend is `sqlite`. I guess I am either missing some configuration or just forgot to do something simple. Ideas?

Comment: What middleware do you have installed?

Comment: This is a question about something that is not a problem. The issue I had lied in something totally different (there was some additional code that created most of the mess that prevented objects from being saved). 

Now this question might be misleading for people who really have problems with creating objects. Let's delete it.

Answer (score 4):

`Tag.objects.all()` is a QuerySet.  These do not hit the database until you do something to [evaluate](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) them.  So, how exactly are you using it in your view?  If you are using a generic view and passing the queryset through `extra_context`, for example, it [wouldn't be re-evaluated](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/generic-views/#adding-extra-context).

Also, as an aside, `Tag.objects.create(name = tagName)` will [automatically save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.QuerySet.create) to the db.